# Extract regex that matches dataframe value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of regex `{"WeLove*", "Arizona.*hot", "Mahi*"}`
and a dataframe with certain values that might match with one of the Regex expressions from the regex list.

| _c0 | _c1 | _c2 | _c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arizona is hot | 2020 | 1 | Y |
| Arizona happens to be hot | 2020 | 1 | Y |
| MahiWalia | 2020 | 1 | Y |
| MahiSingh | 2020 | 1 | Y |
| MahiRandhawa | 2020 | 1 | Y |
| WeLovechocolate | 2020 | 1 | Y |

I am trying to find out for each regex how many matches are there in the data frame?

```
"WeLove*"  = 1  
"Arizona.*hot" = 2
"Mahi*" = 3
```

By doing this :

```
regex = spark.read.csv("regex.csv", header=False)

regex_list = regex.select("_c0").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

output = df.select("*", when(col("_c0").rlike("|".join(regex_list)), "True").alias("matches"))

filteredDf = output.filter(output.matches.isNotNull())
```

I was able to find the rows in dataFrame that at least matched with one of the regex in the list but I am not sure how to find which one and then group the rows according to the regex they matched with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the `regex` dataframe to the `df` dataframe using an `rlike` condition, and then get the count for each regex:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

regex = spark.read.csv("regex.csv", header=False)

result = df.alias('df').join(
    regex.alias('regex'),
    F.expr('df._c0 rlike regex._c0')
).groupBy('regex._c0').count()

result.show()
+------------+-----+
|         _c0|count|
+------------+-----+
|Arizona.*hot|    2|
|       Mahi*|    3|
|     WeLove*|    1|
+------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce` along with `when` function to assign a `regex_group` for each row based on the `regex_list` values, then group by the created group column and count :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

regex_list = ["WeLove*", "Arizona.*hot", "Mahi*"]

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "regex_group",
    F.coalesce(*[F.when(F.col("_c0").rlike(r), F.lit(r)) for r in regex_list])
).groupBy("regex_group").count()

df1.show()

#+------------+-----+
#| regex_group|count|
#+------------+-----+
#|Arizona.*hot|    2|
#|       Mahi*|    3|
#|     WeLove*|    1|
#+------------+-----+
```